# How to add Specific Route in Phantomjs Webserver?

Tags: javascript, url, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using **Webserver** to listen request on a particular host. I write ipaddress:port to listen a request. But I want to add specific route into it. for e.g -127.0.0.1:8080/test How I do that please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you would do in node.js. When a request comes in, then you can read the [`url` property of that request](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/method/listen.html) (and parse it yourself) and only answer requests that you want:

```
var webserver = require('webserver');
var server = webserver.create();
var service = server.listen(8080, function(request, response) {
    if (request.url.indexOf("/test") !== -1) {
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write('<html><body>Success!</body></html>');
        response.close();
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 404;
        response.write('<html><body>Nothing to see here</body></html>');
        response.close();
    }
});
```